# reload using importlib on python 3.7

Tags: anaconda, python-3.7, python-importlib

I am trying to use importlib to reload a file. I am using Anaconda prompt on Python 3.7 but I can't understand why it says "'importlib' is not defined" when I try importlib.reload, but it works when I use from x import reload.

Here it works:

```
>>> import script1  
win32  
1267650600228229401496703205376
SpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpam  
import importlib  
>>> from importlib import reload  
>>> reload(script1)  
win32
1267650600228229401496703205376
SpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpam
```

Here it does not work:

```
Python 3.7.3  
>>> import script1  
win32  
1267650600228229401496703205376  
SpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpam  
import importlib  
>>> importlib.reload(script1)  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `import importlib` command is evaluated within `script1` module (while it's being imported), so it's available within `script1` only. When the import of `script1` is finished, whatever is imported within this module gets out of scope. Try evaluating `import importlib` explicitly after `import script1` if you want to reload it. Your input/output should look like this:

```
Python 3.7.3  
>>> import script1  
win32  
1267650600228229401496703205376  
SpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpamSpam  
import importlib
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(script1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mjarosie